# NoClassDefFoundError with classpath

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, jnetpcap

I'm attempting to run a program using the command:

```
java Honey -cp ../../jnetpcap-1.3.0/jnetpcap.jar
```

and am getting the title error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jnetpcap/Pcap
        at Honey.main(Honey.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnetpcap.Pcap
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could point out to me what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: check if the files in your jar are in the right directories -- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html

Comment: jar tf jnetpcap.jar | grep Pcap.class gives me
org/jnetpcap/Pcap.class

Comment: not sure, but since it depends on a native library, maybe it can't deal well with "indirections" in the path. Ensure the native library is installed and copy the jar to the same dir as your "Honey" class and try again

Comment: Attempted, but same error.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: i'm using Ubuntu Linux

Comment: which java are you using?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_45"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must explicitly tell the JVM where is the native library.

Try something like this

sudo ../jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java -Djava.library.path=/home/leoks/Downloads/jnetpcap-1.3.0 -cp .:jnetpcap.jar Honey

I don't know how "Honey" looks like, so I've used this instead

http://jnetpcap.com/?q=examples/classic

For this specific example, since it requires some special permissions, I've run it using sudo.

For this example I've downloaded jnetpcap for ubuntu 64-bit from here

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jnetpcap/files/jnetpcap/1.3/jnetpcap-1.3.0-1.ubuntu.x86_64.tgz/download

I've used Oracle JDK 1.8.0_45 and Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 2):

`-cp` like all JVM run-options only works if you put it *before* the name of the class you want to run, or the `-jar` option if you use that to run the manifested main-class. Any tokens *after* the classsname or `-jar` name are passed as arguments *to your program*. Once you fix that you will find that you need your classpath to contain both the jnetpcap jar and also your class(es), so you need something like

```
 jar -cp .:path/to/jnetpcap.jar Honey 
 # on Windows use ; instead of :
```